# Play Framework doesn't find package on clean project

Tags: java, scala, playframework, jvm

I created a new project on Play Framework 2.3.2 with Scala. I added two packages models and utils. Created a class in each package and made an import into the model from utils and I get this error :

```
[error] /media/hadareanrares/Media/Projects/TestingScala/app/models/Page.scala:3: not found: object utils
[error] import utils._
[error]        ^
[error] one error found
```

Tried "_root_.utils._" and I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. class in utils package didn't have "package utils" specified. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it by juggling with the class in the utils package.

I saw that IDEA IntelliJ detected the class in utils by importing as import _root_.ClassName, disregarding the utils package.

Then I moved ClassName to the root package, app. The compiler complained that it couldn't import _root_.   so I moved the class back to the utils package and it seemed to have fixed it somehow after a rebuild.

The key thing that made it work was dragging the class from root to the utils package. It seemed to have updated links everywhere. But, have I not had the help of IDEA, how else would I fix this? I would like to use a simpler text tool, Sublime, that doesn't have the Scala integration that IDEA has.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
activator reload // Reload the current application build file
```

and

```
activator update // Update application dependencies
```

then

```
activator idea // to recreate your IntelliJ files
```

Comment: First two commands have no effect to fixing the bug, and the last step doesn't complete because it complains about the bug and stops.